# JBoss EAP 6.2 remove the management user

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have added a management user using add-user.sh script. I see no option to remove it. How should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `mgmt-users.properties` file in your domain or standalone's configuration directory to remove the line associated with the user.